# Solving for the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. to different bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Here is the question:
Suppose $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is linear and has matrix
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}4&9\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
with respect to the basis $B = \{(1,-1),(-3,2)\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. What is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

My attempt:
Let the matrix we want be $X$.
Then $$X = QAP^{-1}$$
where$$Q = P = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -3\\1 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$

This does not give me the answer in their solution.
Rationale behind my working out: $Q$ is the matrix of the identity map of the basis vectors $B$ in domain, and standard basis $S$ in the codomain. Similarly for $P$. Then $X$ is the matrix of $T$ w.r.t standard basis $S$ in domain and codomain.
I thought that they gave us the matrix of $T$ w.r.t basis $B$ in domain and codomain, so we could just find $X$ with this?

Comment: I think the first entry in the second row of the matrix $Q$ should be $-1$

Comment: How come? I had the same as $P$ since the identity map of $B$ and then coordinate vectors w.r.t codomain (standard) will be $(1,1)$?

Comment: $B=\{(1,-1),(-3,2)\}$.

Comment: Right, thanks haha.